# Serving Static Content NGINX

Tags: caching, nginx, proxy

I'm new to [**NGINX**](http://nginx.com/). I don't know a lot about it yet, but I'm trying to.
I'm curious what is the best way to serve the static contents from my page using NGINX. The main reason why I want to serve the static contents is that I want put less load on my application servers, and increase the page load speed.

---

## I came across

a couple good articles that help me put these together this post : [here](https://serversforhackers.com/nginx-caching/), [here](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776660/how-to-make-nginx-serve-static-content-like-js-css-html),  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806893/use-nginx-to-serve-static-files-from-subdirectories-of-a-given-directory).

But everything is still a little clear.

---

## Configuration

File Path : `etc/nginx/default`

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name default;
    root /home/forge/site/public;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://43.35.49.160/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
}
```

---

## Test/Result

After saving my file, I run `service nginx reload`.

Next, I tried run : `curl -X GET -I  http://45.33.69.160/index.php`

I got:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Fri, 08 May 2015 15:14:55 GMT
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkhPa2kwK1wvd2kxMFV0TURzYnMwSXFnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkFpSFpvakNjcGp0b0RWcVViYXJcLzRHbmo3XC9qbStYc2VzYVh4ZHVwNW45UGNQMmltZEhvSys1NjhZVzZmckhzOGRBUk5IU1pGK084VDF1ZmhvVkZ4MlE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjliMzc5NWQ4MWRiMjM1NzUxNjcyNGNmYWUzMGQyMDk3MjlkYTdhYzgxYTI0OGViODhlMTRjZTI4MWE5MDU2MGYifQ%3D%3D; expires=Fri, 08-May-2015 17:14:55 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Iklhb041MkVBak0rVm5JeUZ0VVwvZ3pnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IitRUFlzQzNmSm1FZ0NQVVFtaTJ4cG1hODlDa2NjVDgzdXBcLzRcL0ZSM1ZPOTRvRGo5QjQ1REluTUM3Vjd3cFptV3dWdHJweTY3QW5QR2lwTkZMUlNqbnc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjIxOTZkYzM5ODE0N2E4YmQzODMxZGYzMDY3NjI4ODM1YWQxNGMxNDRlZDZmMGE1M2IwZWY2OTU4ZmVjOTIyMjkifQ%3D%3D; expires=Fri, 08-May-2015 17:14:55 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
```

Then, I tried run `curl -X GET -I  http://45.33.69.160/css/custom.css`

I got :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.3
Date: Fri, 08 May 2015 15:16:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
Content-Length: 2890
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 May 2015 03:02:38 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "554ad5ce-b4a"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Why do I see  `Cache-Control: no-cache` and I just set up the cache ?

Everything is just unclear to me right now.

---

## Questions

Can someone please make it clear on how to :

- configure this properly
- test that configuration if it is work
- see the different between caching and not caching
- benchmark it and print out that report on a page or CLI

?

Comment: I see no-cache only in case of the PHP request. It will show up in that request as that won't be cached.

Comment: I don't understand you what you mean ? can you elaborate more please ?

Comment: @Neo : Do you have any suggestions for me ?

Comment: What I meant is that the .php file resource will not be cached as it is seen in the response headers. Though I don't see any 'no-cache' headers in the .css response headers.

Comment: @Neo :  Can you show me how I test my static content is loaded properly ?

Comment: Try running the request through: https://redbot.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `Cache-Control: no-cache`

As said in [this answer about no-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383359/1587329), which links to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1), the `Cache-Control: no-cache` should tell the *user agent* and *in-between caches* which caching style to use (namely to revalidate each time with the server). This applies if you use nginx exclusively. If you use it as a pass-through, you [need to set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10995522/1587329) [proxy_ignore_headers](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_ignore_headers), like

```
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
```

#### Config

Apart from that: in the [NGINX reference about content caching](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/caching/), it says to put the line

```
    proxy_cache_path /data/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:10m;
```

in the `http` part, followed by

```
        proxy_cache one;
```

in the `server` part.

#### Testing

[In this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/434915/nginix-proxy-caching-how-to-check-if-it-is-working/434935#434935), it says to test caching behavior by adding the `X-Cache-Status` header via the config file

```
add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
```

[Its answer](https://serverfault.com/a/434935) states that

> You can view headers with
>
> - the Firefox addon firebug
> - the Chrome debugging console
> - cURL (curl -I )